# How to send message from server to mutiple clients by sockets in python?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a server and a client writen in python. I can communicate between server and client in both sides, but I can not send message from one client to other connected clients and I only recive this message at client I have send it from. I do not know how to moddifie my code to be able to send message to mutiple clients. The only thing i had estabilished is that i have to use **Queue** module. I also tried using lists but error showed up in server :

```
[WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed
because the socket is not connected  and (when sending on a datagram
socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

Server code :

```
import socket
import threading
import queue

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER,PORT)
FORMAT = "UTF-8"
DISC_MESS = "END!"
q = queue.Queue()

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)
conns = []
addrs = []

def handle_client(conn, addr,que):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected")
    connection = True
    #print(que.get())
    while connection:
        mess_len = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if mess_len:
            mess_len = int(mess_len)
            mess = conn.recv(mess_len).decode(FORMAT)
            send_mess(mess)

            if mess == DISC_MESS:
                connection = False
                conn.close()

            print(f"[{addr}] {mess}")


def send_mess(mess):
    for conn in conns:
        #addr_no_cn = addr[0]
        #addr_corr = (addr_no_cn,PORT)
        #conn.connect(ADDR)
        message = mess.encode(FORMAT)
        mess_len = len(message)
        send_len = str(mess_len).encode(FORMAT)
        send_len += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_len))
        conn.send(send_len)
        conn.send(message)

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENNING] Server is listenning on {ADDR}")
    while True:
        (conn,addr) = server.accept()
        conns.append(conn)
        #addrs.append(addr)
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target = handle_client, args=(conn, addr, q))
        thread1.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.active_count() -1}")

print("Server is starting... ")
start()
```

Client code :

```
import socket

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = "UTF-8"
DISC_MESS = "END!"
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)


def send_mess(mess):
    message = mess.encode(FORMAT)
    mess_len = len(message)
    send_len = str(dlug_wiad).encode(FORMAT)
    send_len += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_len))
    client.send(send_len)
    client.send(message)


message = ""
client.settimeout(10)
while message != DISC_MESS:
    message = input("Send message: ")
    send_mess(message)
    message_recv = client.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
    if message_recv:
        message_recv = int(message_recv)
        decoded_recv_mess = client.recv(message_recv).decode(FORMAT)
        print(f"Recived message : {decoded_recv_mess}")
```

Thanks every one in advance for help.

Comment: error can suggest that you try to send message to client which is not connected or it is already diconected but you didn't remove it from list `conns`

Comment: in server code you can always use `SERVER = '0.0.0.0'`. There is no need to use `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`.

Comment: there is good rule to use english names for variables - it helps to understand code if someone doesn't speek polish (PL: jest taka dobra zasada używania angielskich nazw zmiennych bo to pomaga zrozumieć kod jeśli ktoś nie mówi po polsku). See more: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: you may have common problem. Method `client-server` expects that client as first sends message and later wait for response from server - and server never send message as firts but it has to wait for client  request. There is also other problem: client uses `input()` to wait for message from user - and this block all code - and it can't receive other message from server at the same time. It would need to run separated thread with separated socket only to get messages and the same time.

Comment: I know about that rule but i didnt notice that function name, and I'm really sorry for that. Also your last advice may be the solution for my problem and I will try it as fast as i can. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @furas You were right, the input was the problem here. I used multiprocessing and it kind of work now, but it still a lot of work to work as intendet. Thank you for your help!